# My list should make 4 tkinter images but it only makes 2 photo

Tags: python, tkinter

This program should make multiple images while also plotting a specific point on the y and x intercept. But for some reason it only pops up two images. The first image is the last y and x inter strings in the list.With the second image being the code after .after. It should take all the list values and convert it into images, with the correct y and x inter. So there should be like 4 images. Please run the code your self and help me please. If you figure it out could you please show me the updated code.

````
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


def ShowAnotherWin(i):
    win = Toplevel()
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:/Users/capture.PNG'))
    win.geometry('420x544+' + i + '+' + i)
    canvas =Canvas(win, width=420, height=560)
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image= image, anchor=NW)
    canvas.pack()
    win.overrideredirect(1) 
    win.mainloop()


YourImageList = ['0', '50', '100', '150']


root = Tk()
for i in YourImageList:
    root.after(0, lambda:ShowAnotherWin(i))


image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:/Users/capture.PNG'))
root.geometry('420x560+1000+0')
canvas = Canvas(root, width=420, height=560)
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image= image, anchor=NW)
canvas.pack()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.mainloop()
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue you are suffering from here is being caused by [late binding](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures).

By the time the closure variable `i` is passed to `ShowAnotherWin()`, the for loop has completed and `i` is left with its final value of `'150'`. This is because closure variables are looked up at the time the function is called.

To resolve, you can use a default argument for the lambda closure that will be bound immediately:

```
for i in YourImageList:
    root.after(0, lambda i=i: ShowAnotherWin(i))
```